# PHP - Get only single image from many inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php based system.
Actually it is a product display system.
In the database there are 2 main tables called `products`, `product_images`
**product**

```
pid | product_name | weight | price | ....
```

**product_images**
`iid | pid | image_path`
*Admin panel allows backend users to upload many images for a product.*

That is the database table structure.
There are many products in the system.
There is a page which displays all the products with a image.
I used the below code to print all the products.

```
$getProduct = mysqli_query($con, "select p.*, pi.* from products p left join product_images pi on p.pid = pi.pid");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getProduct)){
                    echo $row['product_name'].'<br>';
                    echo'<img src="../../thumbnails/'.$imgD['image_name'].'">';
                }
```

When I run the above code everything prints nicely but the images.
Image there is a product called "Sample Product #1" and has 4 photos. 
The display page displays the product 4 times(It prints all 4 images).

```
<image> Sample Product #1<br>
<image> Sample Product #1<br>
<image> Sample Product #1<br>
<image> Sample Product #1<br>
```

What I need is to print the product name with the first image of the product.
How can I do this?

Comment: Keep track of last printed `product_name` and don't print it again till you don't get same product name.
`
$getProduct = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT p.*, pi.* 
FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.pid = pi.pid 
ORDER BY product_name");

$productName = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getProduct)){
 if($productName != $row['product_name']) {
  $productName = $row['product_name'];
     echo $row['product_name'].'<br>';
 }
    echo'<img src="../../thumbnails/'.$imgD['image_name'].'">';
}
`

Comment: @RonakDhoot - Now the product name prints only once but all the images of the product prints. I need to print only the first image of the product.